# Using iframe for google maps embed api in multi device Delphi

Tags: android, google-maps, delphi, iframe, twebbrowser

Currently I have a code like this to display a google map with my current location in my TWebBrowser

```
procedure TForm1.LocationSensor1LocationChanged(Sender: TObject; const
    OldLocation, NewLocation: TLocationCoord2D);
begin
  var URLString := Format('https://maps.google.com/maps?q=%s,%s&output=embed', [Format('%2.6f', [NewLocation.Latitude]), Format('%2.6f', [NewLocation.Longitude])]);

  WebBrowser1.Navigate(URLString);
end;
```

If I use my URL as `https://maps.google.com/maps?q=%s,%s` then it works properly but when I use my URL as `https://maps.google.com/maps?q=%s,%s&output=embed` then it will prompt an error "The Google Maps Embed API must be used in an iframe" as shown in the picture[image]

Is there a way I could have an iframe in my delphi project?

Comment: Why are you using `Format()` inside of `Format()`? Use this instead: `var URLString := Format('https://maps.google.com/maps?q=%2.6f,%2.6f', [NewLocation.Latitude, NewLocation.Longitude]);` That said, if omitting the `embed` parameter works, why do you want to use the `embed` parameter? An `iframe` is an HTML element, so if the API wants an `iframe`, you will have to dynamically create an HTML page containing an `iframe` that requests the updated URL, and then load that HTML page into the browser.

Comment: Noted on the `Format()` and I'm using the `embed` parameter because i just want the google map without the search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, Google's embedded map wants to be hosted in an HTML `<iframe>`. `TWebBrowser` has a [`LoadFromStrings()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.WebBrowser.TCustomWebBrowser.LoadFromStrings) method that you can use for that purpose, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.LocationSensor1LocationChanged(Sender: TObject;
  const OldLocation, NewLocation: TLocationCoord2D);
begin
  var URL := Format('https://maps.google.com/maps?q=%2.6f,%2.6f&output=embed', [NewLocation.Latitude, NewLocation.Longitude]);
  var HTML = Format('<iframe src="%s" width="%d" height="%d" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>', [URL, <DesiredWidth>, <DesiredHeight>]);
  WebBrowser1.LoadFromStrings(HTML, URL);
end;
```